# am developping an app on android handling sqlitedatabase every time I click on a button my app stops this is the logcat msg and the code

Tags: java, android

```
2021-11-18 20:16:12.067 21990-21990/com.example.db1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-11-18 20:16:12.069 21990-21990/com.example.db1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.db1, PID: 21990
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14230)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14230) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965) 
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT _id, data FROM table
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:703)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1865)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1712)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1583)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1751)
        at com.example.db1.MyDbAdapter.getData(MyDbAdapter.java:27)
        at com.example.db1.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:34)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14230) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318) 
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: If the app crashes then it was you that cause it to crash. If you check the Logcat message properly, you would see what caused it.

Comment: And I think *Android Room* adds compile-time lint checks for you than you dealing with runtime errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT _id, data FROM table`See this?Something wrong in your sql.

And look at here:

```
   at com.example.db1.MyDbAdapter.getData(MyDbAdapter.java:27)
    at com.example.db1.MainActivity.show(MainActivity.java:34)
```

check these two lines,something wrong here